# What causes the following error: Incorrect Syntax near ','?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, insert

I'm trying to insert information to a table on a sql express 2008 database, and when I try to insert the fields, I get the error "Incorrect Syntax near ',' " Can someone explain to me what in my code is causing this problem?

```
protected void insertworkshop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CIS489_3\WILDLIFE;Initial Catalog=WildLife_Education;Integrated Security=True;"))
        {


            SqlCommand CmdSql2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [tblWorkshop] ([WorkshopName], [WorkshopBeginingDate], [WorkshopEndingDate], [WorkshopLocation], [InstructorID])VALUES (@WorkshopName, @WorkshopBeginingDate, @WorkshopEndingDate, @WorkshopLocation, @InstructorID)", conn2);
            conn2.Open();
            CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkshopName", workshopinsertname.Text.ToString());
            CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkshopBeginingDate", workshopinsertstart.Text.ToString());
        CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[WorkshopEndingDate", workshopinsertend.Text.ToString());
        CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkshopLocation", workshopinsertlocation.Text.ToString());
        CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InstructorID", insertinstructorid.SelectedValue.ToString());


        CmdSql2.Connection = conn2;
        CmdSql2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn2.Close();
        UpdateInsertWorkshop.Update();
        this.addnewworkshop_ModalPopupExtender.Hide();

    }
```

Comment: do you have all column as varchar datatype?

Comment: I would verify each of your strings are actually in the format you expect.

Comment: Bad key?  `"@[WorkshopEndingDate"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your code, there is an extra `[` on the following line:

```
 CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[WorkshopEndingDate", workshopinsertend.Text.ToString());
```

Should be:

```
 CmdSql2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkshopEndingDate", workshopinsertend.Text.ToString());
```